# I cannot find what might be the reason for this ? Maybe an open connection ? please resolve

Tags: node.js, mysql2, node-mysql2

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Unexpected packet while no commands in the queue
    at Connection.protocolError (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:354:17)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:401:12)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:70:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:328:25)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection.protocolError (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:357:10)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/home/param/Desktop/HRMSFIRST-HOv5.0/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:401:12)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_UNEXPECTED_PACKET'
}
```

This is my package.json

```
"author": "liver",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "country-flags-svg": "^0.2.5",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.8",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "express-ip": "^1.0.3",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "formidable": "^1.2.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "got": "^9.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.7.0",
    "node-cron": "^1.2.1",
    "node-ses": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "paypal-recurring": "^1.1.0",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.8.1",
    "promise": "^8.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.11.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to check for open connection everything is fine. addcommand() of mysql2 throws this error. I tried to search for the same there were few solutions with modification :false in webconfig.js.

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql?

Comment: const mysql = require('mysql2');
const env = require('../enviornment/env');
let connection;
module.exports = {
    connect: ()=> {connection = mysql.createPool(env.sql); return connection;},
    connection: () => {
        console.log('connection starting');
        return connection;}

};

Comment: is your database on your localhost? are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: sql: {                                                // mysql configs
        host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || 'localhost', //rds endpoint
        user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME || 'abc',
        password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD || 'XYZ',
        database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME  || 'dbdbdb',
        port: process.env.RDS_PORT || 3306,
        ssl: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }